# Windows 10 will not boot anymore

Tags: bootcamp, windows, startup, macos, partition

Urgent! I have an existing Windows 10 installation via Bootcamp which has been on my Mac for months without issue. However for ages I have been wanting to read my Mac partition from Windows which it doesn't allow me to do, so I looked online which suggested making a third partition for both OS's to read from.

So I made a 10GB partition on Disk Utility which worked fine, and my Bootcamp drive is still there **(it wasn't formatted, I can still view all Windows files from OS X)**, only problem now is Windows will not boot! If I hold down alt at the white screen, only my Mac partition shows up. When I go to system preferences and choose boot options, bootcamp is still there!? I removed the 10GB partition but it has not remedied the problem... I don't get it, please help!!

Answer (score 1):

I can help you if you've a live USB linux distribution, ex. Ubuntu.

1. Boot into Ubuntu live USB by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> when upon
   restarting and choose `EFI Boot`.
2. Choose to `Try Ubuntu`.
3. Open Terminal by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.
4. Install `efibootmgr` by entering `sudo apt-get install efibootmgr`.
5. After installing it, check `bootOrder` and boot values by entering `sudo efibootmgr`.
6. Usually you OS X boot value is `0x80`, please get your Windows value.
7. You can change booting order by `sudo efibootmgr -o <comma separated boot values>`.
8. Adjust your bootOrder assuming your Windows boot values is 0x01 then you should enter `sudo efibootmgr -o 1,80` **<- Windows first**. *So that your Mac should try booting to Windows first as you mention that you need an urgent solution*.
9. Reboot to your live USB again and readjust the bootOrder by letting Mac boot into OS X first by `sudo efibootmgr -o 80,1` **<- OS X first**.
10. Don't use any 3rd party bootloaders as you can easily adjust everything manually.

Advice:
Format your shared partition as `ExFAT` =)